# Setting a jpg as the background for a UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, background, jpeg

I know this is a very beginner question, but I'm obviously a beginner. I have already made a my TabBar but I want to set the background of one of the views as a (jpg) I created. I need to add the background in code (not IB) so that I can allow rotation and resizing when the iphone is rotated.

-thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `UIImageView`, which is a subclass of `UIView`. You can create it as follows:

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
[myImage release];
```

...so here I've created a UIImageView that uses a JPG called 'myImage' (it will automatically resize the view to fit the image), added it to my view controller, and then cleaned up my memory.

Comment: is there any chance i actually could have it not auto rotate. I know im contradicting myself but i created a new image so it doesnt have to rotate.

Comment: Sure, that'll be a property of you view controller. There will be a delegate method inside your view controller (if you've used Apple's templates, if not you'll need to insert it yourself), `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` - just have it return `NO` for the rotations you don't want to support.

Comment: oh yeah I already did that but it still wouldnt fill the space, but i found that if you go into the IB and in the View Attributes in the drop down menu Mode, select "Center" and the view will remain completely still. Thank you for the answers tho.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one to set an image as a background for a view programmatically:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an instance of UIImageView to your view, and set it's image to an instance of UIImage created using your file.

You can add the image view in IB or in code -- there's nothing about doing it in IB that would prevent you from resizing, rotating, etc.